# SQL interview questions

Tags: sql, oracle

Table-1

```
Col1 col2
11     A   
26     B
31     C
43     D
```

Table-2

```
Col1 col2
16     E   
46     F
39     G
42     H
```

And need output is

```
Col1 col2 Col1 col2
11     A   16   E
26     B   46   F
31     C   39   G
43     D   42   H
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It’s not even a question really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  a (col1, col2) as
  4    (select 11, 'A' from dual union all
  5     select 26, 'B' from dual union all
  6     select 31, 'C' from dual union all
  7     select 43, 'D' from dual
  8    ),
  9  b (col1, col2) as
 10    (select 16, 'E' from dual union all
 11     select 46, 'F' from dual union all
 12     select 39, 'G' from dual union all
 13     select 42, 'H' from dual
 14    ),
 15  -- find something to join rows on - for example, row number. Your example shows that
 16  -- values are sorted by COL2
 17  a2 as
 18    (select col1, col2, row_number() over (order by col2) rn from a),
 19  b2 as
 20    (select col1, col2, row_number() over (order by col2) rn from b)
 21  -- join a2 and b2 on RN
 22  select a2.col1, a2.col2, b2.col1, b2.col2
 23  from a2 join b2 on a2.rn = b2.rn
 24  order by a2.col1;

 COL1 COL2  COL1 COL2
----- ---- ----- ----
   11 A       16 E
   26 B       46 F
   31 C       39 G
   43 D       42 H

SQL>
```

Comment: I got it..Thank you @littlefoot

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2 from table1 as t1 
left join table2 as t2 on 1=1
```

Try this

Comment: Did **you** try it? It won't work for (at least) two reasons: tables, when using aliases, can't have the `as` keyword (it is not `table1 as t1` but `table1 t1`). Furthermore, what you did is a **cross join** which produces 16 rows (4 from the first table * 4 from the second table).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on ascii(t1.col2)+4 = ascii(t2.col2);
```

Note: this only works with the specific input provided, but why not? It just goes to show that providing minimal input and expected output is not sufficient. You have to explain what rules the input should follow and what rules the processing should follow.

Littlefoot answers a different question than I do, but even he silently makes some assumptions. For example, he decided not to show any output if there are unmatched rows on one side or the other.

The correct real-world answer to this interview question would be to list the questions one would have to ask before being able to supply an appropriate answer.